# XAMPP の MySQL が起動できない

Tags: mysql, xampp

XAMPP から MySQL (MariaDB) を勉強始めた初心者です。

XAMPP コントロールパネルで MySQL 起動ボタンをクリックしましたが、当初は起動できましたが、password を使用するように変更したら起動できなくなりました。

エラーメッセージを添付しますので、同様のご経験のある方のご連絡をお願いします。

**XAMPP コントロールパネル画面**
[image: XAMPP コントロールパネル画面]

**XAMPP エラーログ**
[image: XAMPP エラーログ]

Comment: 「password を使用するように変更したら」と書かれてますが、実行したコマンドなど、何を実施したか、具体的に書けますか？